# What is the most efficience way to compute the nth root, log(x) and e^x of a given number in solidity

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, math

This is just something that came out of curiousity.I have been looking for methods for this all over the internet and can't seem to find any. Is there an actually efficient method or any method for that matter that can help us find the nth rooth, log(x) and e^x in solidity??